# Find all functions $f(x,y)$ which have continuous second partials and satisfy $f_{yx}=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm having trouble trying to solve this question.
How do you start such a problem?

I'm pretty sure it's not simply all functions whose powers of $x$ and $y$ are $1$ right?

i.e $$f(x,y)=ax+by+c$$ where $a,b,c$ are constants, or variables that do not depend on $x$ or $y$

Comment: Well, you could work your way backwards. $f_{yx} = 0$ implies that $f_x$ is a function independent of $y$.

Comment: Hint: Taylor expansion.

Comment: Try $f(x,y) = F(x) + G(y)$ with $F,G\in C^2$.

Comment: Thanks!
What if, instead, the function must satisfy $f_{yx} = 1$ ?

Comment: Add $xy$ to that ( a particular solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating to recover $f$, bearing in mind that the "constant" of integration in one variable will be a function of the other.
$$
\int f_{xy}\mathrm dx=f_y=g(y)\implies\int f_y\mathrm dy=f(x,y)=\int g(y)\mathrm dy+H(x)
$$
Calling $\int g(y)\mathrm dy=G(y)$ gives 
$$
f(x,y)=G(y)+H(x)
$$